# ActiveMQ Artemis cluster suddenly not redistribute message to another node

Tags: activemq-artemis

- Environment:

  - OS: Ubuntu 20.04
  - ActiveMQ Artemis: 2.25.0
  - Java: OpenJDK 11.0.16

I have a two-node cluster composed of broker_1064 and broker_1164. I code a pair of small program (Producer and Consumer) to monitor and test cross-node producing and consuming message.

Producer will send a test message to the queue `mdms.lpi.test_it` in broker_1064. And then Consumer will try to consume the message from the same queue in broker_1164 or vise versa.

Before starting a new test, Producer cleans the queue it will produce, and Consumer cleans the queue it will consume.

Based on the log of Producer and Consumer as below, Consumer can receive messages at begin. Few time later ( maybe one hour or few hours), then suddenly Consumer can not receive message. But on the other direction, Consumer can still get message.

From below logs, before 15:31:37, you can see that no matter which broker Consumer consumes, it can get messages. But after 15:31:37, only through the way `Producer-->broker_1064 --> broker_1164-->Consumer`, Consumer can get message at broker_1164. For the way of `Producer -->broker_1164 --> broker_1064-->Consumer`, Consumer get nothing. And since that time, the situation keeps the same. I have checked the queue `mdms.lpi.test-it`'s attribute `Message count`. Two brokers all show zero.

I have tried other queues and get the same result.

The only way of making it back to two-way are all accessible again I know is to choose one broker and then clean all its data folder and restart the broker.

```
15:31:05.118 [main] INFO : 2022-09-28 15:31:05 ====  TEST LPI [Cluster node ---> node]  ===================
15:31:05.363 [main] INFO : [O] Producer -->[broker_1064]-->[mdms.lpi.test_it]-->[broker_1164]--> Consumer get: [2022-09-28 15:31:05: TEST MESSAGE]
15:31:05.587 [main] INFO : [O] Producer -->[broker_1164]-->[mdms.lpi.test_it]-->[broker_1064]--> Consumer get: [2022-09-28 15:31:05: TEST MESSAGE]
15:31:06.527 [main] INFO :
15:31:06.527 [main] INFO :
15:31:36.539 [main] INFO : 2022-09-28 15:31:36 ====  TEST LPI [Cluster node ---> node]  ===================
15:31:36.752 [main] INFO : [O] Producer -->[broker_1064]-->[mdms.lpi.test_it]-->[broker_1164]--> Consumer get: [2022-09-28 15:31:36: TEST MESSAGE]
15:31:36.978 [main] INFO : [O] Producer -->[broker_1164]-->[mdms.lpi.test_it]-->[broker_1064]--> Consumer get: [2022-09-28 15:31:36: TEST MESSAGE]
15:31:37.896 [main] INFO :
15:31:37.896 [main] INFO :
15:32:07.897 [main] INFO : 2022-09-28 15:32:07 ====  TEST LPI [Cluster node ---> node]  ===================
15:32:08.112 [main] INFO : [O] Producer -->[broker_1064]-->[mdms.lpi.test_it]-->[broker_1164]--> Consumer get: [2022-09-28 15:32:08: TEST MESSAGE]
15:32:13.372 [main] WARN : [X] Producer -->[broker_1164]-->[mdms.lpi.test_it]-->[broker_1064]--> Consumer get: []
15:32:19.543 [main] INFO :
15:32:19.543 [main] INFO :
15:32:49.553 [main] INFO : 2022-09-28 15:32:49 ====  TEST LPI [Cluster node ---> node]  ===================
15:32:49.833 [main] INFO : [O] Producer -->[broker_1064]-->[mdms.lpi.test_it]-->[broker_1164]--> Consumer get: [2022-09-28 15:32:49: TEST MESSAGE]
15:32:55.113 [main] WARN : [X] Producer -->[broker_1164]-->[mdms.lpi.test_it]-->[broker_1064]--> Consumer get: []
15:33:01.356 [main] INFO :
15:33:01.356 [main] INFO :
15:33:31.370 [main] INFO : 2022-09-28 15:33:31 ====  TEST LPI [Cluster node ---> node]  ===================
15:33:31.663 [main] INFO : [O] Producer -->[broker_1064]-->[mdms.lpi.test_it]-->[broker_1164]--> Consumer get: [2022-09-28 15:33:31: TEST MESSAGE]
15:33:36.899 [main] WARN : [X] Producer -->[broker_1164]-->[mdms.lpi.test_it]-->[broker_1064]--> Consumer get: []
```

From artemis.log, there is no weird log messages.

broker_1064's `artemis.log`

```
2022-09-28 15:25:26,866 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222061: Client connection failed, clearing up resources for session b93aff09-3efe-11ed-9cad-00505694ca2b
2022-09-28 15:25:26,866 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222107: Cleared up resources for session b93aff09-3efe-11ed-9cad-00505694ca2b
2022-09-28 15:30:33,820 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222061: Client connection failed, clearing up resources for session 702eef0a-3eff-11ed-9cad-00505694ca2b
2022-09-28 15:30:33,822 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222107: Cleared up resources for session 702eef0a-3eff-11ed-9cad-00505694ca2b
2022-09-28 15:35:37,965 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222061: Client connection failed, clearing up resources for session 2579274c-3f00-11ed-9cad-00505694ca2b
2022-09-28 15:35:37,965 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222107: Cleared up resources for session 2579274c-3f00-11ed-9cad-00505694ca2b
2022-09-28 15:40:39,408 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222061: Client connection failed, clearing up resources for session d925b47d-3f00-11ed-9cad-00505694ca2b
2022-09-28 15:40:39,409 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222107: Cleared up resources for session d925b47d-3f00-11ed-9cad-00505694ca2b
2022-09-28 15:45:33,830 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222061: Client connection failed, clearing up resources for session 88a27a95-3f01-11ed-9cad-00505694ca2b
2022-09-28 15:45:33,831 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222107: Cleared up resources for session 88a27a95-3f01-11ed-9cad-00505694ca2b
```

broker_1164's `artemis.log`

```
2022-09-28 13:52:50,172 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241003: Starting embedded web server
2022-09-28 13:52:50,766 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.branding.PluginContextListener] Initialized activemq-branding plugin
2022-09-28 13:52:50,821 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.plugin.PluginContextListener] Initialized artemis-plugin plugin
2022-09-28 13:52:51,096 INFO  [io.hawt.HawtioContextListener] Initialising hawtio services
2022-09-28 13:52:51,107 INFO  [io.hawt.system.ConfigManager] Configuration will be discovered via system properties
2022-09-28 13:52:51,108 INFO  [io.hawt.jmx.JmxTreeWatcher] Welcome to Hawtio 2.15.0
2022-09-28 13:52:51,115 INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.AuthenticationConfiguration] Starting hawtio authentication filter, JAAS realm: "activemq" authorized role     (s): "amq" role principal classes: "org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.RolePrincipal"
2022-09-28 13:52:51,120 INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.LoginRedirectFilter] Hawtio loginRedirectFilter is using 1800 sec. HttpSession timeout
2022-09-28 13:52:51,131 INFO  [io.hawt.web.proxy.ProxyServlet] Proxy servlet is disabled
2022-09-28 13:52:51,136 INFO  [io.hawt.web.servlets.JolokiaConfiguredAgentServlet] Jolokia overridden property: [key=policyLocation, value=file:/opt/broke     r_1164/etc/jolokia-access.xml]
2022-09-28 13:52:51,218 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241001: Embedded web server started at http://0.0.0.0:8161
2022-09-28 13:52:51,220 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241002: Artemis Jolokia REST API available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/console/jolokia
2022-09-28 13:52:51,220 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241004: Artemis Console available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/console
2022-09-28 13:52:51,534 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221027: Bridge ClusterConnectionBridge@5673b0e4 [name=$.artemis.internal.sf.my-     cluster.45f2ecbc-3eee-11ed-9f11-00505694ca2b, queue=QueueImpl[name=$.artemis.internal.sf.my-cluster.45f2ecbc-3eee-11ed-9f11-00505694ca2b, postOffice=PostO     fficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=broker_1164], temp=false]@5c884ab5 targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl (identity=(Cluster-connection-bridge::Clus     terConnectionBridge@5673b0e4 [name=$.artemis.internal.sf.my-cluster.45f2ecbc-3eee-11ed-9f11-00505694ca2b, queue=QueueImpl[name=$.artemis.internal.sf.my-cl     uster.45f2ecbc-3eee-11ed-9f11-00505694ca2b, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=broker_1164], temp=false]@5c884ab5 targetConnector=     ServerLocatorImpl [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=artemis, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFact     ory) ?port=61616&host=192-168-10-64], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]]::ClusterConnectionImpl@1224594628[nodeUUID=89de5070-3eee-11ed-9509-00505694e350,      connector=TransportConfiguration(name=artemis, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=61616&host=192-16     8-11-64, address=, server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=broker_1164])) [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=artemis, factory=org-apache-activemq-art     emis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=61616&host=192-168-10-64], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]] is connected
2022-09-28 16:10:43,621 INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.LoginServlet] Hawtio login is using 1800 sec. HttpSession timeout
2022-09-28 16:10:44,485 INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.keycloak.KeycloakServlet] Keycloak integration is disabled
2022-09-28 16:10:47,348 INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.LoginServlet] Logging in user: admin
```

broker_1064 queue mdms.lpi.test_it's attributes
[image]

broker_1164 queue mdms.lpi.test_it's attributes
[image]

I have tried anothe test. I send some messages to broker_1164 in web console manually. Then  I see the queue `mdms.lpi.test_it`'s below attributes:

```
broker_1164 queue mdms.lpi.test_it
    Message count:3
    Message acknowledged: 0
    Message added: 3

broker_1064 queue mdms.lpi.test_it
    Message count:0
    Message acknowledged: 0
    Message added: 0
```

Then I start my Consumer to consume queue `mdms.lpi.test_it` on broker_1064.

```
broker_1164 queue mdms.lpi.test_it
    Message count:0
    Message acknowledged: 3
    Message added: 3

broker_1064 queue mdms.lpi.test_it
    Message count:0
    Message acknowledged: 0
    Message added: 0
```

Consumer gets nothing.

two brokers are created by below same command (different IP) and plus my little customization (adding my own queue).

```
./artemis create --aio --no-autocreate --clustered --cluster-user lpi_cluster --cluster-password lpi_cluster --data /data/artemis/data --encoding utf-8 --home /opt/apache-artemis-2.25.0 --host 192.168.10.64 --name broker_1064 --no-hornetq-acceptor --no-mqtt-acceptor --no-stomp-acceptor --user admin --password admin --require-login --verbose --java-options "-Xmx96G" /opt/broker_1064
```

broker_1064 and broker_1164 use the same `broker.xml` (only key portion), but different IP and broker name

```
<name>broker_1064</name>
<connectors>
    <!-- Connector used to be announced through cluster connections and notifications -->
    <connector name="artemis">tcp://192.168.10.64:61616</connector>
</connectors>
  <acceptors>
     <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://192.168.10.64:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true;supportAdvisory=false;suppressInternalManagementObjects=false</acceptor>

     <!-- AMQP Acceptor.  Listens on default AMQP port for AMQP traffic.-->
     <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://192.168.10.64:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>
  </acceptors>
  <cluster-user>lpi_cluster</cluster-user>

  <cluster-password>lpi_cluster</cluster-password>

  <broadcast-groups>
     <broadcast-group name="bg-group1">
        <group-address>231.7.7.8</group-address>
        <group-port>9876</group-port>
        <broadcast-period>5000</broadcast-period>
        <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
     </broadcast-group>
  </broadcast-groups>

  <discovery-groups>
     <discovery-group name="dg-group1">
        <group-address>231.7.7.8</group-address>
        <group-port>9876</group-port>
        <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
     </discovery-group>
  </discovery-groups>

  <cluster-connections>
     <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
        <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
        <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
        <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
        <max-hops>1</max-hops>
        <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="dg-group1"/>
     </cluster-connection>
  </cluster-connections>
  <address-settings>
    <address-setting match="mdms.lpi.#">
        <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
        <expiry-delay>172800000</expiry-delay> <!-- 2 days expire, no need ExpiryQueue-->
        <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
        <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
        <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
        <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
        <redistribution-delay>0</redistribution-delay>
    </address-setting>
  </address-settings>
  <addresses>
    <address name="mdms.lpi.test_it">
            <anycast>
             <queue name="mdms.lpi.test_it"/>
            </anycast>
    </address>
  </addresses>
```

I have no idea how to make this two-node cluster work normally. Any suggestion is appreciated.